# QGIS curved labels don't show up in print composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, scale

I use QGIS 2.14.2. I set up labels names of a line vector and set it up as curved - looks like in this screenshot[image]

But when I want to print it in print composer it doesn't show up [image]

It only shows labels if they aren't curved. [image]

What can I do to fix it. Curved labels are looking really nice (for compared to parallel one.

Comment: Try to reduce the font size, or use map unit for fonts.

Comment: I tried...nothing happens.

Comment: I think is too short line for that text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with map scale. Too short line for those words.

[image]

Comment: I see that is connected with scale of a map in print composer.

Comment: 'connected with scale of a map in print composer', I'm having similar problems with symbol display in the print composer window - set to A5 portrait scale - some symbols have to be increased to 30 pixels and they appear overly large in the print composer window, but appear the required size when I export the file as a PDF.  Previously at 10 pixels, the symbols looked normal in the print composer window, but when exported as a PDF on the map they looked really small.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that the "Maximum angle between curved characters" (Layer properties->Labels->Placement) might have to be adjusted. If the line segment is too tightly curved, the label will not be displayed if it requires a higher angle than the one specified.

This seems to be the case, since the missing label corresponds to the line with the highest curvature.

Comment: This helped me when drawing lines for manual labeling. The curves were so close to the default of 25° that even a few pixels difference in the calculation at different map scales made a few labels disappear.