# Why the street label is not showing in a feature in QGIS 2.14.2?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Why this street label is not visible even with zoom?

It has 'name' in it...

[image]

[Here_qgis2.14.2_file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwaMRO9PzoGnSzlWRlhINDZva1k)

Comment: You mean when you zoom in towards the feature, you still cannot see the label?

Comment: Yes, but just until now. I can see it now when zoom it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the road is too short for the text to fit on, or it's too curvy.  [Check here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/194586/73835) for a similar solved question.  A solution could be to either abbreviate  the label, or simplifying the line might help.

EDIT: if you don't want to change the road then you could use rule-based labelling and create a new rule solely for that single label:

```
"name" = 'R. da Fonte do touro'
```

For that particular label I'd suggest setting the placement as below the line, offset by a slight distance.  You could then also reduce font size to fit better along the line. Repeat or add other labels with similar issues.

Comment: 1 -  if I change scale of a map in print composer I can see it. 2 - If i delete nodes and the line change to straight line I can see it at the first scale, that is what I want. I need the curved line! Is there another way? I tried spacing and "Placement > Maximum angle between curved characters", with no luck...